# Checking is 5x5 matrix according to bingo rules or not

Tags: python-3.x

How to write if statements into python code, which rules are listed next. The code has to check is any 5x5 matrix is bingo or not. Here is my code:

```
                      #Rules are simple
 table=[[12,17,34,48,70],  #first column integers are allowed 1-15         
  [14,25,40,56,61],   #second column integers are allowed 16-30
  [6,30,43,46,72],    #third column integers are allowed 31-45
  [12,16,42,63,65],   #fourth column integers are allowed 46-60
  [4,31,34,49,67]]    #fifth column integers are allowed 61-75

def is_right_matrix(table):
    for i in range(len(table)):
        for j in range(len(table[i])):
            if 
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: I don't think, your comments reflect the Bingo rules well. And your code is incomplete. What should happen after "if    "?

Answer (score 0):

(I hope that i understood your problem correctly.)

You could go through all the numbers and check, whether there are in a range (specific to each column). If there are not, return False.

This (not so pretty) example works for NumPy arrays as well as for "nested" lists (like the one in your table example)

```
table=[[12,17,34,48,70],       
  [14,25,40,56,61],
  [6,30,43,46,72],
  [12,16,42,63,65],
  [4,31,34,49,67]] 


def is_valid_matrix(table):
    for i, col in enumerate(table):  
        # i is the index of the column 
        # (so we know to which column each number belongs)
        # col is the current column

        # if the current column is the first column (indexes start at 0),
        # check for numbers from 1 to 15:
        if i == 0:  
            for n in col:  # go through every number in that column
                # check if that number is not in the range 1 to 15 
                # (range includes the first argument, but excludes the second)
                if n not in range(1, 16):
                # if so, immediately return False 
                # (and therefore exit out of the function)
                    return False  

        # if the current column is the second column,
        # check for numbers from 16 to 30:
        elif i == 1:
            for n in col:
                # check if that number is not in the range 16 to 31 
                if n not in range(16, 31):
                    return False

        # and so on

        elif i == 2:
            for n in col:
                if n not in range(31, 46):
                   return False

        elif i == 3:
            for n in col:
                if n not in range(46, 61):
                    return False

        elif i == 4:
            for n in col:
                if n not in range(61, 76):
                    return False

    return True  # if all "checks" passed/every number was valid: return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is overly complicated solution, but it consists additional uniqueness test (no duplicates allowed in bingo table).

```
def is_valid(matrix):

    floor = range(1, 62, 15)                  
    ceiling = range(15, 76, 15)               

    i = 0

    while i < len(floor):                       
        for low, high in zip(floor, ceiling):    
            for j in list(range(len(matrix)):
                if high < matrix[j][i] < low:
                    return False
        i += 1

    flat = sum(matrix, [])

    if len(set(flat) != len(flat):
        return False

    return True
```